# some random error when staring browser

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, proxy

I am new to ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 16.04 a month ago and facing some problem whenever I try to start my browser (Chrome) and type url an alert box come come and asks for some authentication. with some random url.
I searched for those url but didn't get anything. today I started my postman app for some development work and when I tried to do authentication the below alert came up. I dont know its ubuntu related issue or my browser or the network. so kindly help me.

Network is provided by- My Hostel owner

Pleas help me to resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: It is very likely network related. Could you edit your question with information if you are on your own home network or connected to network in an organization/institution?

Comment: I am connection with network provided by My Hostel owner so its (organization/institution)

Comment: does your network provider give you any authentication to access the internet on the network? Proxy credentials?

Comment: yes its a 10 digit number only no username and other thing

Comment: how do you connect your phone or other windows computers to the internet on this network? Does the owner provide you with any instructions?

Comment: nothing wifi network is available we connect with "OMR PG" and use the 10 digit password

Comment: Okay. Could you please check if you have any proxy settings already present on your system? Go to network and proxy and change the proxy settings to `none`. Also please update if you get this prompt only on this network or any type of connection(eg: mobile hotspot)

Comment: its already to none and I also did applied to system wide. when i connect to mobile hotspot this error doesn't come

Comment: sorry to see this. Please try to forget the Wi-Fi network and add it again. If this doesn't help, I'm sorry. Please add the information that you have given in the comments to your question. Better expert should help you out.